# <c:choose> does not set the expected value based on <ui:repeat var>

Tags: jsf-2, jstl

I have written a code like this:

```
<ui:repeat var="fstDayWk" value="#{calendarBean.date}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="#{fstDayWk == 'Sun'}">
                <c:set var="fstDayWk" value="7"/>
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="#{fstDayWk =='Mon'}">
                <c:set var="fstDayWk" value="1" />
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="#{fstDayWk =='Tue'}">
                <c:set var="fstDayWk" value="2" />
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="#{fstDayWk =='Wed'}">
                <c:set var="fstDayWk" value="3" />
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="#{fstDayWk =='Thu'}">
                <c:set var="fstDayWk" value="4" />
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="#{fstDayWk =='Fri'}">
                <c:set var="fstDayWk" value="5" />
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="#{fstDayWk =='Sat'}">
                <c:set var="fstDayWk" value="6"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:set var="fstDayWk" value="1" />
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
</ui:repeat>
```

But here the value assignment for `fstDayWk` is always 1. Why so? How could I set value to some variable depending upon some condition in JSF?

Answer (score 4):

JSTL tags runs during view build time, when the JSF component tree is about to be built/constructed based on JSF tags in the XHTML file. JSF components such as `<ui:repeat>` in turn runs during view render time, when the built JSF component tree is about to produce HTML code.

So, `<c:choose>` and `<ui:repeat>` does not run in sync as you seemed to expect from the coding. In fact, it's first the `<c:choose>` which runs during view build time and then it's the `<ui:repeat>` which runs during view render time. At that moment when `<c:choose>` runs, the `#{fstDayWk}` which is supposed to be set by `<ui:repeat>` is not available anywhere in the EL scope and thus the `<c:choose>` always ends up in the `<c:otherwise>` condition.

It will work if you use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>`. However, much better would be to use a `Map<String, Integer>` in the model which maintains a mapping between day of week and its index, so that you don't need the whole ugly `<c:choose>` block anymore.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/3343681#3343681)

Comment: How would that Help with `Map<String,Integer>`? Can you please explain me with example?

Comment: Hard to tell as you didn't show that part of code where you actually need the index of day of week. But something like  `<p>Index of day of week is #{bean.map[fstDayWk]}</p>` would be possible this way. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info